# How can I read the video input from a game cube on the iMac screen

Tags: imac, video

The Game cube has a video output wire that looks like this : [image]
How can read the video input on an iMac with this? What do I need to buy? What software should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an iMac with a Mini-DisplayPort or Thunderbolt port (21/27 inches) .

You can use your iMac in target screen mode using this kind of adapter : [Mini-DisplayPort to Composite](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004VV8R86)

If your iMac is older (20/24 inches) you won't be able to use your iMac with your GameCube.

Comment: looks like a mini-DVI, I'll check that when I see this iMac, but thanks! (+1)

Comment: I check and it looks more like a mini display port, like you said. Thanks again.